# Can I have a virtual firewall forward packets to another virtual machine on the same server?

Tags: virtualization, port-forwarding, xenserver, ipcop

I currently have a web server running Apache using `iptables` for a firewall.  What I would like to do is setup a new machine with [XenServer](http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/lp/lp_1688615.asp) and install two virtual machines--one running [IPCop](http://www.ipcop.org/) and one running Linux with Apache.  Then I would configure IPCop to have the external IP address and forward port 80 to an internal IP on the second virtual machine.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible so long as virtual machine A and B are routable to each other via a private interface through Dom0.

So External -> A -> (A/B internal shared) -> B

Services would need to be listening on the shared internal address and have routes out to A connected networked. If they don't have routing out to A then a port forward would be more applicable on A to B.